# Add a custom column to line items table on WooCommerce My Account Orders View

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, account

I want to add custom column to the existing My Account > Orders > View > Order Detail Table. For better understanding i am attaching images.
First login to WooCommerce My Account then Go to Orders Page and click View order button.

[image]

After click View Order Button on next page want to add custom column with Order Line Item Detail page.

[image]

Please Help.

Comment: You need to edit the template files `order/order-details.php` and `order-details-item.php` changing the desired code using the conditional tag `is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' )` to target My Account Orders View.

Comment: yes sir it is working.. Thank you